# Can I swap any two lithium cells on an MP3 player / camera, etc?

Tags: sensor, lithium, mp3

Lithium batteries commonly have +/- and temp monitor connections. I'm pretty sure I can swap a 290 mAh MP3 battery with a 1400 mAh battery, it will charge very slowly.

Can I swap the temp sensor around on the two? Are they standard resistances / voltages? Can I measure if I can swap them around?

The 290mAh player battery reads +3.8V, sensor 3.5V
The 1400mAh battery reads +4.00V, sensor 3.95V

For now I am just wiring them both in parallel, not wiring the 1400 mAh battery sensor, I doubt it will overheat at 0.1C

It's for a Sansa Clip and a Canon battery.

Comment: The temperature sensors are *often* a standard 10k NTC thermistor, although not always.

Comment: I am not seeking your answer acceptance (I have too many already :-) ) BUT it is not a good idea to accept an early 1st answer until you see if you get more. Some people DO care and may move on without answering and some are apparently discouraged regardless.

Comment: I agree with @RussellMcMahon do not accept my answer unless you fully believe it answers it, best to wait a while before accepting.

Comment: You are not apparently listening to my pot or comments. What you are doing is probably not going to catastrophically destroy the battery BUT it WILL shorten its lifetime. The charger is mean to shut off when Icharge falls to a fixed % of Imax - typically 25%. The small charger will cause the large battery charge current to drop to the ame mA as before so a FAR LOWER % of Imax. In this case 290/1400 =~ 20% of what it should be. This will insert SLIGHTLY more charge but will significantly reduce cycle life. ....->

Comment: ....  The wise thing to do is to remove charger any time you see it has reached fixed voltage of about 4.2V. You will lose relatively little capacity per cycle but greatly extend battery life.
ie LEAVING IT ON CHARGE IS UNWISE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pjc50 says in the comments, the temperature sensor inputs for the batteries are very commonly a 10K NTC thermal resistor. At room temperature, it should be approximately 10K ohms if you can multi-meter it. You can trick charging circuits by placing a 10K resistor to ground on the pin, if you have a battery which does not have a temperature input.

Obviously this is "less safe" than if you had a temperature sense input on the batteries, but if you are charging at a nice low current and it's a proper charging IC with the correct voltage and current charging modes, and safety timers built in etc it will be fine.

Comment: i don't know how the thermal resistor controls the charger, i found that it works without a thermal resistor and charges to a stable 4.20. cool mod! a 25h mp3 charger. thanks.

Comment: It will not be fine in all aspects, alas. The small charger will overcharge the large battery due to I_chg_min being << than designed to be so the battery is driven very close to abs max capacity but loses significant cycle life in the process.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon how do we know what the charger is? It might have very simple constant current and then constant voltage with trickle charge current and may or may not have a safety timer to stop trickle after so many hours. It's possilbe the OP could ID the charge chip used, find a schematic, find out if there is a charge current programming resistor, and modify that to get higher charge currents for their chosen "hack" battery? Would that fix your min charge current issue?

Comment: @KyranF Yes. You are correct that he has not specified what charger he is using explicitly. I read his text as implying, and Occam suggests it is best to assume, that he is using the original "Sansa Clip" charger and that this was correctly designed for the 390 mAh battery. All reputable and even essentially all disreputable devices for sale with LiIon batteries built in use a charger that performs CCCV charging. As I imagine you know it's not that the charging cutoff is to end "trickle charging" - its part of the batteries charging characteristic and the final completeness of charge ....

Comment: .... depends how low you allow the battery to accept charge to. This is quite unlike any common secondary battery chemistries (including NiCd,NimH and Lead Acid). So... it is close to certain [tm] that whatever charger he used, IF it was matched to the 390 mAh battery, will cause slow but certain overcharge in the larger battery. ... | As you note, it may be possible to reprogram the battery termination current, but this is often not the case ...

Comment: ... - typical ICs may have high or low settings and some do have a termination charge rate programming resistor, but this is often linked in a fixed ratio to the charge rate so cannot be  made usefully high. |(I was unable to find a charger IC that met my needs in other areas AND that had this sort of flexibility when I looked for one recently). | So,... overall, its highly likely but not certain, that the charger will overcharge the battery if left on indefinitely AND disconnecting it when Vbat = 4.2V is liable to very usefully prolong battery life.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon As long as the charge voltage is not over-spec, and his battery (which is quite a lot larger than before) maybe does not reach full charge, it will still be a significant improvement as a replacement. I guess with any modification of finely tuned and designed circuits it will never work as perfectly as intended for the original design. I can see what you mean about the charge current being designed more for a much lower capacity battery though, he reports the battery charging to 4.2V so perhaps the charge IC is capable enough to compensate??

Comment: No. The small capacity will OVERcharge a large battery. The small capacity charger will DAMAGE a large battery. LiIon battery charge algorithms are designed so that charging stops when the battery is held at CV (4.2V usually) AND charge current falls to mA = k x mAh. k is maybe 0.5 for a conservative charge, 0.25 for a solid charge and 0.1 for a road warrior I want every mAh NOW and don't care if it dies in 3 months charge. So for a say 1000 mAh battery the soft/hard/vicious limits would be 500 mA, 250 mA and 100 mA. 
 ....

Comment: .... If  I use the 1000 mAh charger on a 10,000 mAh cell then even if it stops at 500 mA which was 50% on the 1000 mAh battery then this is now 500/10,000 = 5% so what WAS a nice soft charge termination becomes road warrior level charging. | Worst case it is possible that if the charger was already set at a rather low % the battery will accept the low low level forever without tripping. Leave it on the charger for say a week (as can happen) and you may kill it dead (killing it live being difficult).

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING:**  Playing with different LiIon batteries in a device always runs the risks of "interesting consequences" to device and/or battery and/or you and/or others. Act accordingly.

Probably.

A possible issue:
If using the 290 mAh charger for the 1400 mAh battery it will not stop charging when it should. Battery will charge to closer to 101% full and lifetime will be reduced.
LiIon / LiPo chargers terminate charging when Ibattery at constant vpoltage falls to some percentage of Imax_allowed.
A charger fr a small battery will not "realise" that a larger battery SHOULD shut down at higher current.

eg if charger shuts down in constant current mode at 25% Imax then I shut_down = 290 x 25% ~= 70 mA.
But 70 mA/ 1400 mA = 5% of capacity so shutdown will be when current drops to 5% of Imax.

Temperature sensor is tbd.
What yoiu need to know is resistance from (probably) -ve terminal to sensor terminal. Chceck 12st that there is NO voltage between the two terminal and then measure both batteries with temperature the same in each case.
If they are the same then probably OK.
If different then systems may always charge (fire or not) or never charge. This is 'overcomeable - comment if needed.

---

ADDED:

From a comments discussion:

A small capacity charger will OVERcharge a large battery.
The small capacity charger will DAMAGE a large battery.
LiIon battery charge algorithms are designed so that charging stops when the battery is held at CV (4.2V usually) AND charge current falls to mA = k x mAh.
k is maybe 0.5 for a conservative charge,
0.25 for a solid charge
and 0.1 for a "Road Warrior I want every mAh NOW and don't care if it dies in 3 months"  charge.

So for a say 1000 mAh battery
the soft/hard/vicious limits would be
500 mA, 250 mA and 100 mA.
If I use the above 1,000 mAh charger on a 10,000 mAh cell
then even if it stops at 500 mA which was 50% on the 1000 mAh battery
then this is now 500/10,000 = 5%
so what WAS a nice soft charge termination becomes road warrior level charging.

Worst case it is possible that if the charger was already set at a rather low % the battery will accept the low low level forever without tripping.
Leave it on the charger for say a week (as can happen) and you may kill it dead (killing it live being difficult).

Comment: Thanks! that's very helpful. it is charging and the battery is close to 4.19 it went up gradually from 4.00 in just under an hour. If i check that the battery is never over 4.22, it's topped up fine?

Comment: @ufomorace It will be topped up very fine indeed (ie over-fine) if charged to 4.22 by that charger - as - as above - it does not stop where it should. This should not cause catastrophic events as Vmax is OK BUT will reduce cycle life. If you stop as soon as you notice it as "levelled out" (4.2V or similar) you will much onprove cycle life and only reduce per cycle capacity 10%-20% max.

Comment: It seems that the battery monitoring system on the mp3 player is controlling the Vmax at exactly 4.20 so everything's ok, still i will charge it safely for a number of weeks to avoid burning the house :) i took out the original battery altogether, great warning there!

Answer (score -1):

Worked awesome, charge took 4x longer, so did dicharge... check voltages and first charges on replacements with high c rate specs of modern cromium chemistries and it should be pretty damn safe. 4.2 max 3 min and .2c or .5c charge is imperative.